# Can't create an Azure Service Fabric project using VS2017 Enterprise

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

As soon as I click on the Service Fabric App template I get a window with error: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, version 16.0.0.0...The located assembly does not match the assembly reference. (I do run in Administrator mode.)

This happens whether I create a new Solution or try to add the project to an existing solution.

I am using the latest updates for VS and for the Azure Service add-ons.

Note: No problem with VS 2019 on the same machine